# User Macro fill parameter from script

Tags: javascript, confluence

i´m creating a UserMacro in Confluence and I want to fill a DATE from a script into my Search Macro.
I get the DATE but I´m not able to get this date into the searchform.

I´m currently stuck with the id=weeknumber, it will show as normal Text but I can´t get in the macro above.

```java
##noparam

<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="eb77a3a2-ee58-4ebd-bfa5-d24235e7bbbf" ac:name="search" ac:schema-version="1">
<ac:parameter ac:name="query"> ###need Date here###
</ac:parameter>
</ac:structured-macro>

<div id='weeknumber'></div>

<script>
function getWeekNumber() {
  var today = new Date();
 return today.toISOString().substr(0, 10);    
}
AJS.toInit(function ($) {
    $('#weeknumber').text(getWeekNumber(new Date()));   
  });
</script>
```